# Minimal generating set for product of groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, direct-product

Let $S_1$ be a minimal generating set for a group $G_1$, $S_2$ be a minimal generating set for a group $G_2$. $T_j:G_j\to G_1\times G_2, j=1,2 $. Then can we say $T(S_1) \cup T(S_2)$ is a "minimal" generating set for $G_1\times G_2$?

Comment: consider $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I think you mean $T_1(S_1) \cup T_2(S_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a generating set, which we can see as follows. Given any element $g$ of $G_1 \times G_2$, $g$ has the form $(g_1, g_2)$. We can express $(g_1, 1)$ as a combination of elements from $T_1(S_1)$, and similarly $(1, g_2)$ as a combination of elements from $T_2(S_2)$. Then the product of those two combinations gives $g$ as a combination of elements from $T_1(S_1) \cup T_2(S_2)$.

However, it is not always a *minimal* generating set, as @RobertChamberlain points out. For $G_1 = \Bbb{Z}/2$ and $G_2 = \Bbb{Z}/3$, a minimal generating set for each of the $G_i$ has a single generator, call it $\gamma_i$. The combined generating set is $\{(\gamma_1, 1), (1, \gamma_2)\}$, but $G_1 \times G_2$ is cyclic, so a minimal generating set for $G_1 \times G_2$ has only one element. In fact $(\gamma_1, \gamma_2)$ generates $G_1 \times G_2$.

Comment: What will happen if the semidirect product of G1 and G2 was considered? Will it be the same then also?

Comment: My guess is that $T_1(S_1) \cup T_2(S_2)$ is not even guaranteed to generate $G_1 \rtimes G_2$ in that case.

Comment: It's still a generating set in that case. (More generally, if you have $G$ a group with a normal subgroup $N$, and a subset $X$ of $G$ that generates $N$ and projects to a generating set of $G/N$, then it generates $G$. This is easy to prove.) It might still not be minimal, the same counterexample works, of course. In general, minimality of generating sets is not a property that behaves very well with respect to various operations.